# multiple filter option control

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to create an option button which will run a filter on a a subform of records which are already being filtered.

As soon as the option button is launched, the filter created within the subform is no longer valid.

I am trying to determine the following 2 things with minimal success on both:

1- is it possible to run a filter on a table already being filtered and maintain the rules for both filters?

2- if not, i am trying to incorporate an and statement in the code for the option button filter but have little success...

basically, i would like the following two statements to be incorporated into one statement using AND

Me![frmProjectSubPhase04].Form.Filter = "[overall_status]='delayed'"   AND
Me![frmProjectSubPhase04].Form.Filter = "[exercise]=is not null"

I hope to hear from someone soon on this one because it is really bugging me.. Thanx

Comment: How is the original filter being applied?  Could you do it through the underlying query if it's consistent/constant.  If it's a customised filter applied by the user (right-click in subform) that you want to maintain it's more fiddly.  I seem to recall doing something similar a while back which combines the filter from within the subform and the one from the option buttons or ComboBox, let me try to recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you need to combine the existing `.Form.Filter` with the new criteria from the option button.  However, there are situations which may cause problems with the simplest solution.  I am assuming that the option button on the main form is `optDelayedOnly` with a caption `Delayed Records Only`.

1. If there is a field `status` in the subform which the user may have already filtered on then this could lead to a conflict.  You would need to decide whether you should remove the user-defined criteria on that field before adding your own criteria.  **My solution does not test for this**.
2. When the user unchecks the `optDelayedOnly` button then you need to remove this element of the filter.  The filter may also include the pre-existing criteria specified by the user previously such as `[exercise] IS NOT NULL`.
3. Access has a habit of adding an additional set of brackets around portions of the filter such as `((([status]='delayed'))) AND ([example_table].[exercise] = 'my exercise')`

So if you plan to let them apply their own filters within the form I would avoid trying to implement the option button as it will lead to headaches and requires thorough testing for various filtering scenarios and sequences.

This said, I have knocked up a sample of the code you could use if your situation is as I have assumed.  The screen shot shows the way I have set up my form and the code behind follows.

[image]

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Me.sfexample_table.Form.Filter = ""

End Sub

Private Sub optDelayedOnly_AfterUpdate()

    Dim strFilter As String, strDelayedOnlyFilter As String

    strFilter = Me.sfexample_table.Form.Filter          ' get the current filter from the form
    strDelayedOnlyFilter = "[status] = 'delayed'"       ' define the new status filter

    If Me.optDelayedOnly = False Then
        strFilter = Replace(strFilter, strDelayedOnlyFilter, "")    ' remove the DelayedOnly filter if it exists
        Do Until InStr(strFilter, "()") = 0                         ' remove any empty parentheses if they exist
            strFilter = Replace(strFilter, "()", "")
        Loop
        strFilter = Trim(strFilter)
        If Left(strFilter, 3) = "AND" Then strFilter = Trim(Right(strFilter, Len(strFilter) - 3)) ' remove a leading AND
        If Right(strFilter, 3) = "AND" Then strFilter = Trim(Left(strFilter, Len(strFilter) - 3)) ' remove a trailing AND
    Else
        ' this is when the option box is selected so apply a filter on top of the existing (user-specified) filter
        ' test the existing filter
        If Len(strFilter) > 0 Then
            strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & strDelayedOnlyFilter  ' tag our DelayedOnly filter on the end (AND is required)
        Else
            strFilter = strDelayedOnlyFilter                        ' just use the DelayedOnly filter (AND is not required)
        End If
    End If
    ' MsgBox strFilter - used for debugging

    ' now assign the new filter to the subform and apply it
    Me.sfexample_table.Form.Filter = strFilter
    Me.sfexample_table.Form.FilterOn = True

End Sub
```

Please feel free to comment for further clarification of if my assumptions are wrong.  Please note that I have not used an identical form name, and my field is called `status` rather than `overall_status`.  I can send you the Access file I used if you require.

Comment: Thanks so much for your dedication to my problem...  I will give this a try and let you know..  May i please ask another question..  I am not sure if this issue is linked but it may be.. I am going to post a question to the public called "FILTER CONFLICT"...   I would appreciate it if you could have a look for i feel you may know the answer..  Thanks again...  your code looks spot on with what i am trying to do...

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua I hope this helps.  I notice from your profile that you have not marked any of the answers to your prior questions on Stack Overflow as accepted.  It's good practice to upvote and mark the best answer as accepted, assuming that it solves the problem described.  I saw your other question and will give it some thought after this question is resolved satisfactorily.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks again Matt..  Yes, i am new to this culture and didnt realise that my feedback was required...  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

If your existing filter is

```vbs
Me![frmProjectSubPhase04].Form.Filter = "[overall_status]='delayed'"
```

and you want to add a second condition you should be able to use code like the following

```vbs
Me![frmProjectSubPhase04].Form.Filter = _
        "(" & Me![frmProjectSubPhase04].Form.Filter & ") " & _
            "AND ([exercise] IS NOT NULL)"
```